# Commutator table for Lie algebras

Tags: tables

What function in LaTeX (`\begin{}`, etc.) would you use to create a commutator table for a Lie Algebra?

I tried to use the generator at http://www.tablesgenerator.com/ but it doesn't compile properly.

Edit: I need something as simple as

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question is not clear at the moment.

Comment: I edited and put an image of what I am looking for.

Comment: Your `iop` reference image looks like a simple `tabular` environment.

Comment: I tried in this environment but it does not compile properly. Do I need to use a particular package to use it ?

Comment: Something like `\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline a&b\\\hline c&d\\\hline\end{tabular}` where `$math_expression$` is substituted for `a`, `b`, etc.

Comment: Also, if you want to direct your comment at a prior commenter, you must include @Steven B. Segletes in your comment, and then I will be notified.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: @Steven B.Segletes : It works ! Thanks. But how do I do to take off the borders ? I just want them on the first left column and for the top row.

Comment: p.s.  No special environments are needed for a basic `tabular`, though there are more advanced forms like `tabularx` that require their own packages.

Comment: The `|` characters in `{|c|c|}` define vertical lines around centered columns, while `\hline` denotes horizontal lines.  You can remove them to suit.

Comment: @Hypern: Anyway, there are too much lines in the table

Comment: CAREFUL: It isn't clear to me in your table of [X,Y] brackets whether X is the horizontal variable or the vertical one. You will want to make that clear somehow, or the reader might get all of the signs wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest, but not best setup... just to give a clue how to start with...

The height of the cells can be somewhat controlled by changing the value `\tabularextravskip`

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{mathtools}%
\begin{document}

\newlength{\tabularextravskip}
\setlength{\tabularextravskip}{2ex}

\begin{tabular}{|*{6}{c|}}
\hline
& \(V_{1}\) & \(V_{2}\) & \(V_{3}\) & \(V_{4}\) & \(V_{5}\) \tabularnewline
\hline
\(V_{1}\) & & & & & \tabularnewline[\tabularextravskip]
\hline
\(V_{2}\) & & & & & \tabularnewline[\tabularextravskip]
\hline
\(V_{3}\) & & & & \(-\dfrac{1}{\lambda}V_{4}\) & \(\dfrac{1}{\lambda}V_{5}\) \tabularnewline[\tabularextravskip]
 \hline
\(V_{4}\) & & & \(\dfrac{1}{\lambda}V_{4}\) & & \( V_{3}\) \tabularnewline[\tabularextravskip]
\hline
\(V_{5}\) & & \(-\dfrac{1}{\lambda}V_{5}\) & \(-V_{3}\) & & \tabularnewline[\tabularextravskip]
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**improved version with centered mathematical columns and multirow usage**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}%
\usepackage{mathtools}%
\begin{document}

\newlength{\tabularextravskip}
\setlength{\tabularextravskip}{4ex}


\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}m{#1}<{$}}


\begin{tabular}{|*{6}{M{1cm}|}}
\hline
& & & & & \tabularnewline
& V_{1} & V_{2} & V_{3} & V_{4} & V_{5} \tabularnewline
& & & & & \tabularnewline
\hline
V_{1} & & & & & \tabularnewline[\tabularextravskip]
\hline
V_{2} & & & & & \tabularnewline[\tabularextravskip]
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{$V_{3}$} & & & & \multirow{1}{*}{$-\dfrac{1}{\lambda}V_{4}$} & \multirow{3}{*}{$\dfrac{1}{\lambda} V_{5}$} \tabularnewline[\tabularextravskip]
& & & & & \tabularnewline
 \hline
V_{4} & & & \dfrac{1}{\lambda}V_{4} & &  \multirow{3}{*}{$V_{3}$} \tabularnewline[\tabularextravskip]
\hline
V_{5} & & & -\dfrac{1}{\lambda}V_{5} & -V_{3} & \tabularnewline[\tabularextravskip]
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{spacing}{:\quad}
\captionsetup{
  labelsep = spacing,
  tableposition = top,
  font = small,
  labelfont = sc
}

\newcommand*\factor{\frac{1}{\lambda}}
\newcommand*\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}
\newcommand*\Bstrut{\rule[-0.9ex]{0pt}{0pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
 \caption{Commutator table for Lie algebras.}
  \begin{tabular}{>{$}c<{$} | *{5}{>{$}c<{$}}}
   \toprule
          & V_{1} & V_{2} &          V_{3} &          V_{4} &         V_{5}\Bstrut\\
   \hline
    V_{1} &       &       &                &                &              \Tstrut\\[1ex]
    V_{2} &       &       &                &                &                     \\[1ex]
    V_{3} &       &       &                & -\factor V_{4} & \factor V_{5}       \\[1ex]
    V_{4} &       &       &  \factor V_{4} &                &         V_{3}       \\[1ex]
    V_{5} &       &       & -\factor V_{5} & -        V_{3} &                     \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output1]

or maybe the following to get equal column width

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{spacing}{:\quad}
\captionsetup{
  labelsep = spacing,
  tableposition = top,
  font = small,
  labelfont = sc
}

\newcommand*\factor{\frac{1}{\lambda}}
\newcommand*\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}
\newcommand*\Bstrut{\rule[-0.9ex]{0pt}{0pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
 \caption{Commutator table for Lie algebras.}
  \begin{tabular}{>{$}c<{$} | *{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{1cm}<{$}}}
   \toprule
          & V_{1} & V_{2} &          V_{3} &          V_{4} &         V_{5}\Bstrut\\
   \hline
    V_{1} &       &       &                &                &              \Tstrut\\[2ex]
    V_{2} &       &       &                &                &                     \\[2ex]
    V_{3} &       &       &                & -\factor V_{4} & \factor V_{5}       \\[2ex]
    V_{4} &       &       &  \factor V_{4} &                &         V_{3}       \\[2ex]
    V_{5} &       &       & -\factor V_{5} & -        V_{3} &                     \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

Answer (score 1):

Two variants, with a different alignment and row spacing obtained with the `makecell` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{spacing}{:\quad}
\captionsetup{
  labelsep =spacing,
  figureposition = bottom,
  tableposition = top,
  font =footnotesize,
  labelfont = sc
}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\newcommand*\factor{\mfrac{1}{\lambda}}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\makegapedcells
 \caption{Commutator table for Lie algebras.}
  \begin{tabular}{@{\hskip 0.8em}>{$}c<{$\enspace}!{\vrule width 0.5pt} *{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{1cm}<{$}}!{\vrule width 0.8pt}}
          & V_{1} & V_{2} & V_{3} & V_{4} & V_{5}\\
   \Xhline{0.5pt}
    V_{1} & & & & & \\
    V_{2} & & & & & \\
    V_{3} & & & & -\factor V_{4} & \factor V_{5} \\
    V_{4} & & & \hphantom{-}\factor V_{4} & & \hphantom{\factor} V_{3} \\
    V_{5} & & & -\factor V_{5} & \hphantom{\factor}- V_{3} & \\
 \Xhline{0.8pt}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\mbox{}

\begin{table}[! h]
\centering\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\makegapedcells
 \caption{Commutator table for Lie algebras.}
  \begin{tabular}{@{\hskip 0.8em}>{$}c<{$\enspace}!{\vrule width 1pt} *{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{1cm}<{$}}}
          & V_{1} & V_{2} & V_{3} & V_{4} & V_{5}\\
   \Xhline{0.6pt}
    V_{1} & & & & & \\
    V_{2} & & & & & \\
    V_{3} & & & & -\factor V_{4} & \factor V_{5} \\
    V_{4} & & & \hphantom{-}\factor V_{4} & & \hphantom{\factor} V_{3} \\
    V_{5} & & & -\factor V_{5} & \hphantom{\factor}- V_{3} & \\[-2.5ex]
```

& 
      \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

```
\end{document}
```

[image]